# Cómo agrupar un array de objetos por valor y concatenar demás valores en uno solo?

Tags: javascript, json, array, reactjs

Tengo una duda, cómo puedo hacer para mapear y reducir un array como este:

```
[
    {
      "Table": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "cycle": {
            "id": 1,
            "Start": "2020-10-10"
          },
          "col": {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "TableA"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "cycle": {
            "id": 1,
            "Start": "2020-10-10"
          },
          "col": {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "TableB"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "cycle": {
            "id": 1,
            "Start": "2020-11-10"
          },
          "col": {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "TableC"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

y quisiera poder hacer esto con el array:

```
[
    {
        Start: "2020-10-10",
        Name: [TableA, TableB]
    },
    {
        Start: "2020-11-10",
        Name: [TableC]
    }
]
```

Alguna sugerencia para llegar a lo que necesito?

Estoy escribiendo una app en React y quiero mostrar esos valores agrupados en una tabla.

Tendría que quedar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté con esto:

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow class="table-secondary">
            <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    {array.map(row => {
        return (
            <TableBody>
                <TableCell rowSpan={AQUÍ HAY QUE CONTAR CUANTOS DE CADA NAME PARA CADA CYCLE}>
                    <TableRow>
                        {row.cycle.Start}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <TableRow>
                        {row.col.Name}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableCell>
            </TableBody>
        );
    })}
</Table>
```

Lo anterior solo lista todos los elementos, pero no me los agrupa por `cycle.Start`.

Y hay que tener en cuanta el `rowSpan` para que fusione las filas para un un mismo `cycle.Start`.

La idea es agrupar los valores en un nuevo array, mostrarlos y ver el tamaño de `Name: [TableA, TableB]` por ejemplo para ver el tamaño y colocarlo en `rowSpan`.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar lo que has intentado y no termine cerrada.

Comment: @Triby Gracias! Ahí la edité. Podés ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta es la forma mas sencilla que tienes de hacerlo se crea un hashmap para usar como llave la fecha y poder agrupar la tablas por otro lado debes recorrer el objeto para sacar la información

```js
var objeto ='[{"Table":[{"id":1,"cycle":{"id":1,"Date":"2020-10-10"},"col":{"id":1,"Name":"TableA"}},{"id":2,"per":{"id":1,"Date":"2020-10-10"},"col":{"id":2,"Name":"TableB"}},{"id":3,"cycle":{"id":1,"Date":"2020-11-10"},"col":{"id":2,"Name":"TableC"}},{"id":3,"cycle":{"id":1,"Date":"2020-11-10"},"col":{"id":2,"Name":"Tablej"}}]}]'
// el array es distinto para ver como se agrupan por fechas
var myHash = {};
JSON.parse(objeto)[0].Table.forEach(x => {
debugger;
    if(!myHash[x?.cycle?.Date]){
        myHash[x?.cycle?.Date]= [x.col.Name]}
    else{
        myHash[x?.cycle?.Date].push(x.col.Name)
    }})
  
Object.entries(myHash).forEach(x=>console.log(x[0]+" "+x[1]))
```

El método Object.entries() devuelve una matriz de pares propios de una propiedad enumerable [key, value] de un objeto dado, en el mismo orden que es proporcionado por for...in (La diferencia es que un bucle for-in enumera las propiedades en la cadena de prototipos).
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries)

Comment: Muchas gracias @enrique-asensio Abajo dejo un comentario para mostrarte lo que hice. Ahora necesito mostrar esos valores como están en la tabla, podés ayudarme con eso? Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Seria recomendable si la publicación es correcta indicarlo he añadido información,
he añadido cambios a la publicacion para lo que indicas

Comment: Buenísimo, funciona. Ahora solo tengo que mostrar el x[1] en dos filas distintas, porque me lo está mostrando en una sola. Cómo lo hago?

Comment: La plataforma stackoverflow es una plataforma para la ayuda de usuarios si necesitas que alguien te resuelva problemas informáticos te aconsejo encarecidamente que contactes con un profesional y le pagues por ello otra opción es intentarlo uno mismo

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya he resueto todo.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo lo sugerido por Enrique:

> Creo que esta es la forma mas sencilla que tienes de hacerlo se crea un hashmap para usar como llave la fecha y poder agrupar la tablas por otro lado debes recorrer el objeto para sacar la información.

Hice

```
var objeto ='[{"Table":[{"id":1,"cycle":{"id":1,"Start": "2020-10-10"},"col":{"id":1,"Name": "TableA"}},{"id":1,"cycle":{"id":1,"Start": "2020-10-10"},"col":{"id":1,"Name": "TableB"}},{"id":1,"cycle":{"id":1,"Start": "2020-11-10"},"col":{"id":1,"Name": "TableC"}}]}]'

var myHash = {};

JSON.parse(objeto)[0].Table.forEach(x => {
//debugger;
    if(!myHash[x?.cycle?.Start]){
        myHash[x?.cycle?.Start]= [x.col.Name]}
    else{
        myHash[x?.cycle?.Start].push(x.col.Name)
    }})
console.log(myHash)
```

Como resultado, en la consola del navegador:

```
{2020-10-10: Array(2), 2020-11-10: Array(1)}
2020-10-10: Array(2)
0: "TableA"
1: "TableB"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
2020-11-10: Array(1)
0: "TableC"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Ahora necesito recorrer ese array para mostrar los valores como lo indica la tabla que está arriba.

Siguiendo la idea

```
[{Start:"2020-10-10",Name:[TableA,TableB]},{Start:"2020-11-10",Name:[TableC]}]
```

Intenté esto

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow class="table-secondary">
            <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    {myHash.map(row => {
        return (
            <TableBody>
                <TableCell rowSpan={row.Name.length}>
                    <TableRow>
                        {row.Start}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <TableRow>
                        {row.Name}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableCell>
            </TableBody>
        );
    })}
</Table>
```

Que da el error:

```
TypeError: myHash.map is not a function
```

Cómo debo hacer para que la tabla quede como la imagen que publiqué en el post? Gracias!

Comment: myHash es un objeto, y .map() requiere de un array de entrada.